# Do blueberry bushes do well around pine stumps?

Tags: blueberries

We are purchasing property next to us that has a row of pine trees. I would like to cut a couple of the tree's down because it will be a sunny and acidic place for blueberry bushes. Can I leave the stumps and plant the berries in a circle around them? The stumps won't bother them if they are planted 3 or 4 feet away, will they?

Comment: It will be very difficult to grow blueberries if there are any rabbits in the county.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can leave the stumps in the ground for food production as phoenix oyster mushrooms love them, and blueberries love pinetrees, so if you've ever seen pinetrees over blueberry bushes you've noticed they're very happy together.

Might I suggest that while the blueberry bushes are establishing themselves you leave the pine trees in the ground as they protect the bushes in their delicate time periods.